# How do I center a subequation?

Tags: equations, subequations

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage[font={color=gray,bf},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={it}]{caption}
\usepackage{vmargin}


\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \ Pr(X_{i,j} = x, Y_{i,j} = y ) =       
   \tau_{\lambda_1, \lambda_2}(x,y)
  \frac{\lambda_1^x exp(-\lambda_1)}{x!}\frac{\lambda_2^y exp(-\lambda_2)}{y!} 
\end{gather}

where

\begin{subequation}
  \tau_{\lambda_1, \lambda_2}(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ c l }
    1-\lambda_1\lambda_2\rho & \quad  \textrm{if } x = y = 0 \\
   1+\lambda_1\rho & \quad \textrm{if } x = 0, y = 1 \\
   1+\lambda_2\rho & \quad \textrm{if } x=1, y=0 \\
   1 - \rho & \quad \textrm{if } x=1, y=1 \\
   1 & \quad \textrm{otherwise }
  \end{array}
\end{subequation}


\end{document}
```

How can I center my second equation?

[image]

Comment: please provide a complete small document that can be run to see this issue I assume you are using amsmath for `gather` how are you definining `subequation` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm new to latex are you just looking for the packages I am using?   
 Edit: I have packages listed now.

Comment: it is always best if your example starts `\documentclass` ends `\end{document}` and is as small as possible to show the problem. As it is, you just have a fragment of code using an environment that is not defined by default so no idea what output you are seeing

Comment: Have you tried just wrapping your second equation inside `\begin{center}` `\end{\center}` ?

Comment: if you are new to latex you really shouldn't be using `epsfig` I wrote that in 1993 as a legacy package for documents that were old _then_ to help convertion to latex2e.

Comment: you have added some code but you have still not defined `subequation`  the code posted produces the error `! LaTeX Error: Environment subequation undefined.` after _any_ error there is no point in looking at the pdf or asking about alignment, the pdf is at best usable as a debugging aid. You should ask about the error message, not the output.

Answer (score 4):

As they say, you're doing it wrong. You'll see lots of errors when you compile your current example code. Here's an updated version that shows a more expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \Pr(X_{i,j} = x, Y_{i,j} = y ) =       
    \tau_{\lambda_1, \lambda_2}(x,y)
    \frac{\lambda_1^x \exp(-\lambda_1)}{x!}
    \frac{\lambda_2^y \exp(-\lambda_2)}{y!} 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \tau_{\lambda_1, \lambda_2}(x,y) = 
    \left\{\begin{array}{ c @{\quad} l }
      1 - \lambda_1\lambda_2\rho & \text{if } x = y = 0    \\
        1 + \lambda_1\rho        & \text{if } x = 0, y = 1 \\
        1 + \lambda_2\rho        & \text{if } x = 1, y = 0 \\
           1 - \rho              & \text{if } x = 1, y = 1 \\
              1                  & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You may consider using the `cases` environment instead of the manually-constructed `array` for the second equation. Also, if you want each of the elements in the second equation numbered, you'll need `numcases` (from the [`numcases` package](//ctan.org/pkg/numcases)).

Comment: Thanks, How would remove numbering from the second equation completely I don't want the label (2)?

Comment: I think that \exp is better instead of \mathrm{exp} because it generates a strange space.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thanks - good suggestion!

Comment: @eoghanPerill: Use `\[`...`\]` instead of `\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}`.

Answer (score 3):

As @Werner mentioned in his answer, you may consider to use `cases` defined in `amsmath` or even better `dcases` defined in `mathtools` package. The later make `cases` content I `display` mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \Pr(X_{i,j} = x, Y_{i,j} = y ) =
    \tau_{\lambda_1, \lambda_2}(x,y)
    \frac{\lambda_1^x \exp(-\lambda_1)}{x!}
    \frac{\lambda_2^y \exp(-\lambda_2)}{y!}
\end{equation}
where
\[
  \tau_{\lambda_1, \lambda_2}(x,y) 
    = \begin{dcases}
        1 - \lambda_1\lambda_2\rho  & \text{if } x = y = 0    \\
        1 + \lambda_1\rho           & \text{if } x = 0, y = 1 \\
        1 + \lambda_2\rho           & \text{if } x = 1, y = 0 \\
           1 - \rho                 & \text{if } x = 1, y = 1 \\
              1                     & \text{otherwise}
  \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do not put \exp instead of \mathrm{exp} different from what the user have reported?

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much for correction of my errors ... it seem that midnight and almost full moon has strong influence on my typing :-(

Comment: Zarko don't worry....I'm here to check on you :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, of course `\exp` is much better than `\mathrm{exp}`. I blindly stole/borrow this part of code from Werner answer ...

Comment: @Zarko Lol, I don't get it.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy, what you not get?

Comment: @Zarko the full moon... I get everything except it, lol. I have seen the full moon, but not when in midnight, on a computer, probably because the curtains and how my computer is placed - So can't get what **effect full moon was** doing to your typing.